# how to use ffmpeg decode udp packet in wasm?

Tags: ffmpeg, webassembly, emscripten

i use this confirgure script compile ffmpeg on ubuntu

```
emconfigure ./configure \
    --prefix=$(pwd)/dist \
    --cc="emcc" \
    --cxx="em++" \
    --ar="emar" \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --target-os=none \
    --arch=x86_32 \
    --cpu=generic \
    --enable-gpl \
    --disable-programs \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-asm \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-everything \
    --disable-debug \
    --enable-protocol=udp \
    --enable-decoder=hevc \
    --enable-parser=hevc \
    --enable-decoder=h264 \
    --enable-parser=h264

emmake make

make install
```

c++ code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <emscripten.h>

extern "C" {
    #include <libavutil/log.h>
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
}
using namespace std;

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
//extern "C" void start(char *src,long callback){
extern "C" void start(){
    int ret = 0;

    /* open input file, and allocate format context */
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, "udp://225.0.0.33:1234?localaddr=192.168.31.3", NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open source file %s, err=%s\n", "udp://225.0.0.33:1234", av_err2str(ret));
        stopDecode();
    }
}
...
```

and build wasm use this command:

```
emcc decode.cpp lib/libavcodec.a lib/libavformat.a lib/libavutil.a -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS="['addFunction']" -s MODULARIZE=1 -s ALLOW_TABLE_GROWTH -I "include" -o wasm/add.js
```

when i call instance._start,console is Could not open source file udp://225.0.0.33:1234, err=**Protocol not available**

i am so confused with this error. in configure script , i use --enable-protocol=udp,and did not --disable-network.

pure c code can run this success,and here is the avcodec_configuration() print

```
--prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x
86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-w32t
hreads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable
-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --enable-libvmaf --enable-vulkan --disable-lib
xcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-a
ac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --disable-frei0r --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libass --enable-l
ibbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-
libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberba
nd --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libu
avs3d --disable-libdrm --disable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-
libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread
--extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20211031
```

is there something i misunderstand?

help please...